# Crankshaft design

Tags: engine-theory, crankshaft

I am wondering why all crankshafts I see are machined so that the piston rod counterweights are all tapered at the rod bearing end of the counterweight? As you can see in the picture the ends of the counterweights of all rod bearings, especially visible in the linked picture on cylinders 3 and 4, are tapered between the main bearing and the rod bearing. The taper goes from the outside of the counter weight toward the the rod bearing. Thank you in advance for any insight into this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

They only put enough material there so it will be strong enough to not destroy itself. If you look at the other end from where the rod journal is at, there's a counterbalance weight. The more weight you have on the rod side, the more material you'd need on the counterbalance side to counteract it.

[image]

Image from: https://www.enginebuildermag.com/2023/11/crankshaft-counterweights/

Comment: Thank you Paulster2. That makes sense. I appreciate it.